# Why is my css in my twig template getting ignored when I apply it to a newsletter issue and then email that newsletter to myself?

Tags: theming

I have created a simplenews Newsletter issue called test1 newsletter.

> [image: Newsletter content]

In the simplenews-newsletter-body--default.html.twig template file I use for the newsletter, I need to add some CSS styles. This is the file content.

```
{% apply inline_css %}
<html>
<body>
<div id="email" style="width:600px;margin: auto;background:white;">
  <!-- Header -->
  <table role="presentation" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#E2FFF8" align="center" style="color: black;">
      <h1 style="font-size: 52px; margin:0 0 20px 0; font-family:Avenir;"> {{ node.getTitle }}</h1>
    </tr>
      </td>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
{% endapply %}
```

When I go to my Drupal site to email myself the test1 newsletter (under the heading "Test email address"), I do receive the email, but it seems to ignore all the CSS styling I have used (and the `<h1>` tag).

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

This is how the email should look like.

[image: screenshot]

How I can fix this issue?

I am using Drupal 9.4.7.

Comment: Can you confirm you are using simplenews with a supported mail system module? The module readme says it supports Mime mail module.

Comment: @cilefen I have the Swift Mailer module installed.